# How to easy add data to existing database (.sql) file in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, sql, database, eclipse

I was wondering if it is possible to easily add data to existing database in Eclipse. I have  a database with about 1000 records, and I don't want to put them in by hand. (In my 'update'-activity.).

I've already tried to go to DDMS - data - data - (project name) - databases, and replace the file for another file with the same name. When I do that, I get an logcat error saying:

```
12-15 08:47:33.495: E/SQLiteLog(4564): (26) file is encrypted or is not a database
12-15 08:47:33.495: E/DefaultDatabaseErrorHandler(4564): Corruption reported by sqlite on database: /data/data/com.jacob.eindproject/databases/Voedsel
12-15 08:47:33.495: E/DefaultDatabaseErrorHandler(4564): deleting the database file: /data/data/com.jacob.eindproject/databases/Voedsel
```

I can 'pull a file from the device'. Can I add data then? Somebody has an idea?

Thank you all in advance,

Jacob

Answer (score 0):

Unless you will be the only user of your app, pushing data to the device or emulator manually is useless. You cannot do that for thousands of users, if for no other reason than they are unlikely to mail you their phones so you can connect the USB cable and push the file.

If your objective is to ship an app that contains starter data for the app, I [recommend `SQLiteAssetHelper`](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper). This is a subclass of `SQLiteOpenHelper` that can automatically unpack a database bundled into your app when the database is first needed.

Comment: Okay, thank you. And what if the app is only for myself? Is there a way to do it then?

Comment: @user3104217 A `.sql` file will not work, because that is not a database, but rather a series of database statements. You are welcome to use a desktop SQLite client to create your SQLite database, then upload it to your device.

Comment: Hmm okay. I've tried to set up the asset helper. But I can't fix it..? Can you please help me? Shall I update this question, or ask a new question? Jacob

Comment: Or should I ask a new question?

Comment: I would recommend that you ask a new question, and provide more details about what you tried and what "I can't fix it" means.

Comment: Please see my other question!